# How to execute exit command while using && and ||?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have two scenarios.

1. `echo a &>/dev/null && echo b || (echo c ; exit 1) ; echo d ;echo e;echo f`

output:

> b
>
> d
>
> e
>
> f

2. `echo a &>/dev/null && echo b || (echo c ; exit 1) ; echo d ;echo e;echo f`

output:

> c
>
> d
>
> e
>
> f

I need my script to exit after the exit command and not execute further commands. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Commands in `( )` are executed in a subshell, so `exit` inside parens only exits the subshell, not the main shell. You can group commands *without* forcing a subshell using `{ }` instead of parens. Note: unlike with parens, you need a space after the `{`, and a semicolon (or ampersand) before `}`.

```
$ eco a &>/dev/null && echo b || { echo c ; exit 1; } ; echo d ;echo e;echo f output
c
logout
```

Also, you should be aware that using `&& ... ||` is *not* the same as an `if then else fi` structure; in particular, if the command between `&&` and `||` (which corresponds to the `then` clause in an `if` statement) should happen to fail, it'll execute what's after the `||` as well. With just `echo b` in there, it's unlikely (but technically possible) for it to fail; if it's more complicated, you can get unexpected results.

As a result, I recommend using `if then else fi` instead of `&& ||` -- it handles the grouping properly without additional hassle, and doesn't have non-obvious execution paths. Unlike `&& ||`, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` would eventually exit the subshell ( `(...)` ), not the script invoking it.

See [Command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

However, `echo b` exit with status 0, so whatever is after the `||` won't be executed.